# How to convert Euclidean Distance to a percentage confidence?

Tags: python, math, machine-learning, image-recognition, euclidean-distance

I have an application doing facial recognition which uses euclidean distance to compare encoded numpy arrays of faces. The algorithm outputs the distance between the two face images as a float value.

I'm able to calculate a distance between images. However, the HTTP API which wraps this functionality needs to be provided a `confidence_percentage`. How can I best achieve this?

I put a temporary hack in place which is:

```py
    confidence_percentage = float(max(0, 100 - distance))
```

The hack isn't ideal as people will filter results by '99' and get poor matches since it's not a real percentage at all.

Comparison SQL:

```
SELECT * from my_stored_encodings 
ORDER BY 
      sqrt(
         power(e1 - TEST_ENCODING_VALUE_0_HERE, 2) + 
         power(e2 - TEST_ENCODING_VALUE_1_HERE, 2) + 
         power(..... etc.... 
     )
```

Comment: This feels more like a maths / statistics question. And I don't think anyone on this site will be able to answer this sufficiently without knowing much more about your application.

Comment: Are you performing any feature extraction? What algorithm are you using for comparison?

Comment: @DoesData Yes 128 feature values. I'll add the comparison sql to the first post

Comment: Euclidean distance might not be a good metric because of [the curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality). Second you have to understand that 99% means a distance of 1. This means that images with a distance of one are not that similar and that similar images must have an even smaller distance. You could try mapping the lowest distance to 100% and the highest to 0% and scale everything in between. However, this probably won't work well either if all of your results have distance ~1. I think you need to re-evaluate your feature extraction and algorithm.